# Error installing compass. Failed to build gem native extension (Compass)

Tags: shell, terminal, installation, rvm, compass-sass

After installation of SASS, i did :

```
gem install compass
```

And this error appears.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20140818-5119-rfb64z.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same issues, after going through the following [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/154292/ruby-rubygems-why-do-i-always-get-error-messages-when-trying-to-install-gems), i have installed the Xcode and my issues is resolved.

Try to install Xcode or apple developer tools.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, if you are using ubuntu (mine is ubuntu 14) like me, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```